# How do I prevent angular from compiling specific dom elements?

Tags: angular

I'd like to be able to render some preformatted html including dom components, but I don't see anyway to prevent the compiler from processing it.

For example, I want to display:

```
<pre>
   <some-component [color]="color"></some-component>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `ngNonBindable`

```
<pre ngNonBindable>
  <some-component [color]="color"></some-component>
</pre>
```

Comment: That prevents bindings like {{ var }}, but doesn't seem to stop it from compiling components or attributes.

Comment: Strangely, there's absolutely no reference of it in official documentation.

Comment: I'd consider it a bug if it doesn't prevent binding. As a workaround you could use `<pre [innerHTML]="propertyWithMyHTML">` because Angular2 doesn't process HTML added this way.

Comment: so I'd need to do something like `<pre [innerHTML]="<some-component [color]="color"></some-component>"></pre>` ??

Comment: If you do it inline you need `<pre [innerHTML]="'<some-component [color]="color"></some-component>'"></pre>` (additional quotes) or `<pre innerHTML="<some-component [color]="color"></some-component>"></pre>` (no bracket) or you add it to a string property `propertyWithMyHTML` in the components class.